# Mega knight crush terminating Ram Rider's charge

Tags: clash-royale

I've been noticing this for a few days. In Clash Royale, my opponent uses Ram Rider to attack my crown towers. Therefore, I played Mega Knight right on top of the Ram Rider while Ram Rider is charging. Mega Knight crushes onto Ram Rider, and Ram Rider propels back. This however stopped her charging. Is this a bug or is this what the developers would've made?

Answer (score 1):

Any knockback or stun interrupts the charge (pushing the unit alone does not). This is normal behavior and also stops the charge of other units, such as the (Dark) Prince and Bandit (if well timed). They will try to restart the charge, if there's still enough room for it or just attack the next target in range.

Using a Mega Knight to counter these chargers is usually a good idea, but there are cheaper cards with the same effect (e.g. Zap, which can be very effective when paired with a damage dealer).

Comment: Mega knight won't stop a princes charge, it will take the hit though

Comment: The log is very effective in stopping charged units as well.